# How to add a custom active class into <a> tag

Tags: wordpress

I've got a custom WordPress theme and custom classes for menu items

In functions.php I have

```
// add link class in top menu
function add_menu_link_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if (property_exists($args, 'link_class')) {
        $atts['class'] = $args->link_class;
    }

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_link_class', 1, 3 );
```

and in header.php

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'top',
    'menu_class' => 'navbar',
    'link_class' => 'nav-link subnav__menu__link',
    'add_li_class' => 'nav-item'
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

I need to add a custom active class into  tag (in the menu), so it would be possible to see which category the post I am currently reading belongs to. In this way.

'link_class' => 'nav-link subnav__menu__link acitve_item'

I googled a lot, but nothing didn`t work for me. Talking about logic, the best solution I have now - to find out the current id category and if the category matches the value from the categories array, do this

$atts['class'] = 'nav-link subnav__menu__link acitve_item';

I`v got a problem with getting a category. This code I googled

global $post;

$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );

gives me 9 identical WP_Term objects and then

```
if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
  var_dump($postcat[0]->term_id );
    }
```

gives me 9 identical ids, I mean repeating current id. Something like this: 591 591 591 591 591 591 591 591 591

Number 9 in this case as I see - the total number of items in the menu (that is, the total number of categories that I have).

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how do I get a category in the singular? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edited to awnser the question correctly

```
    // add link class in top menu
    function add_menu_link_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
      global $post;
      $type = $item->object; //Get the object type
      $id = $item->object_id; //Get the object id
      if($type === "category"){ //Check if the menu item is a category
        if(has_category($id,'',$post)){ //Check if the current object has the category
            $atts['class'] .= " myextraclass"; // Append the extra class
        }
      }
    
        return $atts;
    }
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_link_class', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: $post->ID === $item->ID

Sorry, I don`t get it. Why? How could they possibly have the same value anyway? 

Besides, $post->ID still gives me nine objects instead of a singular and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: the `global $post` is a `WP_Post` object of the page currently loaded and the `$item` in your filter function is a `WP_Post` object of the current item in your menu loop. [Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/)

Comment: Ok I just read your question again I see what your trying to do. ill edit the awnser

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you so much for the explanation, Jasper!